# how to run a powershell script file from a webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, powershell, webserver, asmx

I've created a web service and I'm wanting to run a powershell script from the webservice. I've stored the .ps1 file on the c:\ of the server that the web service is stored. When I call the webservice I get an error saying " *the term --name of method-- is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,or operable program*.

**When i call the webservice from the server it is on it works fine.**

Here is my method:

```
[WebMethod]
public void RunUserProfileSync(string scriptText)
{
    RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
    runspace.Open();

    RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.Add(scriptText);

    // Execute PowerShell script
    pipeline.Invoke();
}
```

so, when calling the webmethod I place "c:\nameoffile.ps1" in the parameters.

What should I do to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [AddScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms569106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method instead of the Add method. Right now it's trying to look for a single command while your script probably has multiple commands.

EDIT: You could also try reading the contents of the file and then passing it to AddScript.

Answer (score 0):

Now this approach may be overkill, but it's worth sharing in case your scripts need to do more powerful operations like interact with a user or display UI.  If this isn't the case, do not choose this approach.  If it is, this approach runs the web service apppool as the SYSTEM account, which then has access to run your script in any user session (not just session 0) as follows:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
        private static extern int OpenProcessToken(System.IntPtr ProcessHandle, int DesiredAccess, ref IntPtr TokenHandle);

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, uint dwDesiredAccess, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, int TokenType, int ImpersonationLevel, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DuplicateTokenEx")]
        extern static Boolean DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, UInt32 dwDesiredAccess, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, Int32 TokenType, Int32 ImpersonationLevel, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateProcessAsUser", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private extern static bool CreateProcessAsUser(IntPtr hToken, String lpApplicationName, String lpCommandLine, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandle, int dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, String lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

        #region Win32 Constants

        private const int NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000020;
        private const int CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400;
        private const int CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000;
        private const int CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010;
        private const uint INVALID_SESSION_ID = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        private static readonly IntPtr WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE = IntPtr.Zero;
        private const int TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 2;
        private const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0X00000008;
        private const int TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0X00000004;
        private const uint MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x2000000;
        private const uint PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION = 0x1000;
        private const uint PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400;

        #endregion


        #region Win32 Structs

        private enum SW
        {
            SW_HIDE = 0,
            SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1,
            SW_NORMAL = 1,
            SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2,
            SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3,
            SW_MAXIMIZE = 3,
            SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4,
            SW_SHOW = 5,
            SW_MINIMIZE = 6,
            SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7,
            SW_SHOWNA = 8,
            SW_RESTORE = 9,
            SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10,
            SW_MAX = 10
        }

        private enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
        {
            WTSActive,
            WTSConnected,
            WTSConnectQuery,
            WTSShadow,
            WTSDisconnected,
            WTSIdle,
            WTSListen,
            WTSReset,
            WTSDown,
            WTSInit
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public uint dwProcessId;
            public uint dwThreadId;
        }

        private enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
        {
            SecurityAnonymous = 0,
            SecurityIdentification = 1,
            SecurityImpersonation = 2,
            SecurityDelegation = 3,
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public int cb;
            public String lpReserved;
            public String lpDesktop;
            public String lpTitle;
            public uint dwX;
            public uint dwY;
            public uint dwXSize;
            public uint dwYSize;
            public uint dwXCountChars;
            public uint dwYCountChars;
            public uint dwFillAttribute;
            public uint dwFlags;
            public short wShowWindow;
            public short cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }

        private enum TOKEN_TYPE
        {
            TokenPrimary = 1,
            TokenImpersonation = 2
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
        {
            public readonly UInt32 SessionID;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public readonly String pWinStationName;

            public readonly WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public int Length;
            public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            public bool bInheritHandle;
        }
```

You can then run functionality which would be similar to mine as follows:

```
       public string Get(string YOURSCRIPT)
        {
            string command = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -File " + YOURSCRIPT;
            bool isSuccessful = false;
            int targetSessionId = 1;
            uint targetWinlogonProcessId = 0;
            IntPtr hToken = IntPtr.Zero, hTokenDup = IntPtr.Zero;
            var procInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("winlogon");
            foreach (Process p in processes)
            {
                if ((uint)p.SessionId == targetSessionId)
                {
                    targetWinlogonProcessId = (uint)p.Id;
                }
            }

            IntPtr hProcess = OpenProcess(MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, false, targetWinlogonProcessId);


            if (OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_DUPLICATE, ref hToken) != 0)
            {
                SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
                sa.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);
                if (DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, ref sa, (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityIdentification, (int)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, ref hTokenDup))
                {
                    STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
                    si.cb = (int)Marshal.SizeOf(si);

                    // interactive window station parameter; basically this indicates 
                    // that the process created can display a GUI on the desktop
                    si.lpDesktop = "winsta0\\default";

                    // flags that specify the priority and creation method of the process
                    int dwCreationFlags = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;

                    // create a new process in the current User's logon session
                    if (CreateProcessAsUser(hTokenDup,  // client's access token
                                                    null,             // file to execute
                                                    command,          // command line
                                                    ref sa,           // pointer to process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                                                    ref sa,           // pointer to thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                                                    false,            // handles are not inheritable
                                                    dwCreationFlags,  // creation flags
                                                    IntPtr.Zero,      // pointer to new environment block 
                                                    null,             // name of current directory 
                                                    ref si,           // pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                                                    out procInfo      // receives information about new process
                                                    ))
                    {
                        isSuccessful = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                        int hr = Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    CloseHandle(hProcess);
                    CloseHandle(hToken);
                }                
            }
            else
                CloseHandle(hProcess);

            return isSuccessful.ToString();
        }
```